# Fast 404 showing page not found

Tags: 7, configuration

I have enabled fast_404 and added the following line in settings.php

```
/**
* Fast 404 settings:
*/
// This path may need to be changed if the fast 404 module is in a different location.
include_once('./sites/all/modules/fast_404/fast_404.inc');

# Disallowed extensions. Any extension in here will not be served by Drupal and
# will get a fast 404.
$conf['fast_404_exts'] = '/^(?!robots).*\.(txt|png|gif|jpe?g|css|js|ico|swf|flv|cgi|bat|pl|dll|exe|asp)$/i';

# Array of whitelisted URL fragment strings that conflict with fast_404.
$conf['fast_404_string_whitelisting'] = array('cdn/farfuture', '/advagg_');

# Default fast 404 error message.
$conf['fast_404_html'] = '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>404 Not Found</title></head><body><h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested URL "@path" was not found on this server.</p></body></html>';

# Call the extension checking now. This will skip any logging of 404s.
fast_404_ext_check();

# Check paths during bootstrap and see if they are legitimate.
# By default, a very plain 404 page is used, because usually errors like this are shown to browsers that only look at the headers. Uncomment this link to use a custom 404 page; this page needs to be in your docroot.
#$conf['fast_404_HTML_error_page'] = './page_not_found.html';

# By default, the custom 404 page is loaded only for path checking. Load it for all 404s with the below option set to TRUE, especially if you are only using fast_404_ext_check().
$conf['fast_404_HTML_error_all_paths'] = FALSE;

$conf['fast_404_path_check'] = TRUE;
fast_404_path_check();
```

If I access the wrong path it shows page not found. If I access the path http://example.com/news/test. It shows page not found, but it is a valid path. and admin menu also breaks after adding above lines.

Answer (score 1):

A year late but since I just ran into all these and no answer has been given then here is how I made things work:

1. Verify that your settings.php has the correct include path.

   include_once('./sites/all/modules/fast_404/fast_404.inc');

   // You may be using something like

   include_once('./sites/all/modules/contrib/fast_404/fast_404.inc');
2. Setting the following to TRUE, I found out, does not work with some path aliases:

   $conf['fast_404_path_check'] = FALSE; // If set to TRUE some aliases do not work
3. Regarding admin menu there is a line of code in admin_menu.module that if you change then it works. Current version is line 66. You are looking for:

   $items['js/admin_menu/cache/'] = array(

   // Change it to

   $items['js/admin_menu/cache/%'] = array(
4. I enabled fast_404_ext_check() and fast_404_path_check() without any issues. Do remember that fast_404_path_check() only works with MySQL.

Remember to flush caches after changing 3.
Hope this helps anyone that bumbs into these issues.